# Threaded tree memory allocation error: cannot convert node* to node

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17, binary-tree

I am writing this in c++ and getting this error "*cannot convert 'createNode(int)::DTBinarytree**' to 'DTBinaryTree*' in
initialization*"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct DTBinaryTree{
    int Ltag;
    int data;
    int Rtag;
    struct DTBinaryTree* left;
    struct DTBinaryTree* right;
};

struct DTBinaryTree* createNode(int data){
    struct DTBinaryTree* root = (struct DTBinarytree**)malloc(sizeof(struct DTBinaryTree));
    root->Ltag = 0;
    root->data = data;
    root->Rtag = 0;
    root->right = root->left = NULL;
    return root;
};
```

can you please help me out where i am doing wrong?

I tried making first line of createnode as

`struct DTBinaryTree* root = (struct DTBinarytree*)malloc(sizeof(struct DTBinaryTree*));`

but it showed one more note as
"*class type 'createNode(int)::DTBinarytree' is incomplete*"

Comment: Why are you using `malloc`? Don't.

Comment: using `new` does not show an error but can you point my mistake in this one.

Comment: Count the stars in `struct DTBinaryTree* root =`. Count the stars in `(struct DTBinarytree**)` The numbers, as far as my counting ability goes, do not match. There's one star on the left and two stars on the right. That's one error. There may or may not be other errors.

Comment: Use new instead of malloc to benefit from constructors and destructors. having to cast malloc is a hint from the compiler that you are on the wrong path and that it will get worse

Answer (score 0):

- You are using `malloc` which, prior to C++20, does not start the lifetime of objects.
- You cast the return from `malloc` to a `DTBinaryTree**` (assuming `DTBinarytree**` was a typo) and try to assign it to a `DTBinaryTree*`. They are not the same, just like an `int*` is not the same as an `int**`.
- You don't have to use `struct DTBinaryTree` other than when defining the class. Simply use `DTBinaryTree`.
- Don't use `NULL`, use `nullptr`.

It looks like C code. In C++, you should probably make a constructor instead:

```cpp
struct DTBinaryTree {
    int Ltag = 0;
    int data;
    int Rtag = 0;
    DTBinaryTree* left = nullptr;
    DTBinaryTree* right = nullptr;
    
    DTBinaryTree(int Data) : data(Data) {} 
};
```

You can now create `DTBinaryTree` instances:

```
DTBinaryTree* foo = new DTBinaryTree(123); // foo->data == 123
delete foo;
```

or as an automatic variable:

```
DTBinaryTree foo(123);
```

Comment: Err, `malloc` does indeed create objects (as in, an object is a storage location for a value). However, no initialiser is invoked. In actual fact, if we look at [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00055.html) we see that C++ is defined such that the `new` operator calls `malloc` and the `delete` operator calls `free`... That aside, I do like your answer, though I'd also like to add that the `(DTBinarytree **)` cast is invalid for two reasons: ¹/ case matters; `T` vs `t`, c'mon now... The variable is `DTBinaryTree *`, so that's what the conversion ought to convert to.

Comment: ²/ yes, in C++ using `malloc` is silly, whereas in C, *casting* `malloc` is silly.

Comment: @autistic `malloc` does not start the lifetime of objects. One could use the allocated memory to do a placement `new` in order to do so though but that seems like a cumbersome way to get the job done.

Comment: @autistic I made a note of the `T`/`t` thing. I assume that's a typo.

Comment: @TedLyngmo your info is outdated, malloc does start lifetime of objects as of C++20.

Comment: @autistic these are not C++ docs. These are implementation details of a particular compiler/standard library.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah, but `malloc` only starts the lifetime of "simple" (fundamental, and classes containing only such fundamental types) since C++20 right? ... or would `malloc(sizeof(std::string))` start the lifetime of a `std::string`? If so, I have a hard time wrapping my head around that :-)

Comment: DTBinaryTree is simple enough (it's an implicit-lifetime type because it's an aggregate, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Implicit-lifetime_class) It would not work with std::string if course.

Comment: @n.m. Ok, but it is a C++17 question so in this case, `malloc` won't start the lifetime of a `DTBinaryTree` (even if it would in C++20).

Comment: "it is a C++17 question" no, it is a question tagged "c++17" for no good reason. Even in C++17 and before, the intent of the standard wasn't invalidating C-style heap allocations. It was a serious defect in the standard.

Comment: @n.m. I assume OP is using C++17 and that's why it's tagged like it is. I agree that it was a defect but that's what OP has to adapt to.

Comment: @TedLyngmo There are better reasons to avoid C-style heap allocations than a miswording of a former standard document. The latter is simply a non-issue, not even worth a passing mention.

Comment: You don't trust the docs provided by those who write the compilers we use? Very well... How about [this](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#11) or [this](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation#footnote-27)? Given that `malloc` _is a standard allocation function_ and _an allocation function _ is what's necessary _to create the object_, surely you'll find yourself backtracking. If the allocation function isn't responsible for the start object lifetime, then the following quote (from the standard) makes no sense: ...cont'd...

Comment: "An allocation function attempts to allocate the requested amount of storage. If it is successful, it returns the address of the start of a block of storage whose length in bytes is at least as large as the requested size."

Comment: @n.m. do you trust gcc devs to know and cite the standards? Because I trust them over you... and fwiw, if you look at the message I wrote above, you can see the footnote I cite where the standard states that the intent is to allow `new` to be implemented using `malloc` and `calloc`, which is I presume what those implementation specific docs elude to. Once again, I trust these docs, _not your words_ (or the words of others in this thread, for that matter, since the vast majority SO is even less authoritative than gcc devs on this topic). I blame the pompous for the fall of this network.

Comment: @autistic The standard *allows* new to be implemented using malloc and calloc, while gcc *implements* new using malloc and calloc. It is important to not confuse the two. gcc is one compiler out of many existing. The question is not specifically about gcc.

Comment: @n.m. very well, I accept that my words were slightly inaccurate but we are otherwise arguing the same point, that [`malloc` does indeed allocate objects](https://eel.is/c++draft/c.malloc#4), and that this last link is the one I ought to have used. I prefer not to do research for ignorant people, so I'll look for texts that are evidential enough to set humble people on the right path, and then go on with my day. It's also interesting to note that C++17 included the term "malloc()-allocated objects"... and all of those mentions of "dynamic storage duration" and the C standard... ‍♂️

Comment: In summary, it's good to see I'm not the only one who thinks that first point is kinda silly. Even in C++14 there appear to be (among the use of the term *"malloc()-allocated objects"*) *"Storage allocated directly with malloc(), calloc(), or realloc() is implicitly declared reachable (see 3.7.4.3) on allocation, ceases to be declared reachable on deallocation, and need not cease to be declared reachable as the result of an undeclare_reachable() call."* I couldn't find a C++98 final draft, but I suspect the same words will be there.